# Distance from centroid to closest edge of a polygon in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon

I'm looking to create the geometry of a multi-lined label like so:

[image: multilined label]

However, I need a way for the width of the overall label to shrink as it get closer to the edge so that it doesn't end up going outside the label, like so:

[image]

I am using the label location as "offset from centroid" so if I can calculate the distance from the centroid to the edge of the polygon, I should be able to make the width of all four lines a percentage of the distance to the edge.

In short, I need an expression to calculate the distance of the visible centroid of a polygon to its edge (the blue line), as pictured below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could try an expression of the form:

`distance(centroid($geometry),exterior_ring($geometry))`

`exterior_ring` gives the (outside) boundary of the polygon as a linestring, and `distance` calculates the shortest distance between two geometries.

Given the rest of your question, you may need to tweak this for edge cases, but it's probably a good starting point.